# Gantt like web scheduler component

Tags: javascript, web-development

I'm looking for a js web based Gantt like scheduler component that displays minute precision. Everything I have found shows day/week/month, I need minute/hour/day. Willing to pay for it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Bryntum,

It has a Gantt Chart and also a Scheduler which specializes in scheduling.

https://www.bryntum.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Essential Gantt for JavaScript](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/gantt) is an option to consider.

[image: Syncfusion Gantt Minute Timeline]

[Sample with source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kujqxj-oepbjm?file=app.component.ts)

We can show the time scale in Hour-Minute combination by setting the timelineSettings.timelineViewMode property as Hour. In this mode, the upper tier displays the hours and the lower tier displays the corresponding minutes of the hour. The following code snippet demonstrates the solution.

app.component.html

```
<ejs-gantt id="ganttDefault" height="430px" [dataSource]="data" [taskFields]="taskSettings" [allowSelection]="true" 
[labelSettings]="labelSettings" height="400px" [projectStartDate]="projectStartDate" [projectEndDate]="projectEndDate" [timelineSettings]="timelineSettings" 
[highlightWeekends]="true"> 
</ejs-gantt>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"; 
import { projectNewData } from "./data"; 
@Component({ 
  selector: "app-root", 
  templateUrl: "app.component.html" 
}) 
export class AppComponent { 
  public data: object[]; 
  public taskSettings: object; 
  public labelSettings: object; 
  public projectStartDate: Date; 
  public projectEndDate: Date; 
  public timelineSettings: object; 
  public ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.data = projectNewData; 
    this.taskSettings = { 
      id: "TaskID", 
      name: "TaskName", 
      startDate: "StartDate", 
      endDate: "EndDate", 
      duration: "Duration", 
      progress: "Progress", 
      dependency: "Predecessor", 
      child: "subtasks" 
    }; 
    this.timelineSettings = { 
      timelineViewMode: "Hour" 
    }; 
    this.labelSettings = { 
      leftLabel: "TaskName" 
    }; 
  } 
}
```

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.